# loging not working in Spring security database integeration with encrypted password

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-3

I have made one application where i have used spring security database driven and password as encrypted. but it is not working. if i configure user credential into xml file as encrypted password it works fine. Please help if anybody know the solution.

I have encoded password using org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder.encodePassword("password",null);
Please, Replay if anyone know the solution. Thank you.

### Here is my applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

<!-- ADD PERSISTENCE SUPPORT HERE (jpa, hibernate, etc) -->
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" >
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>jdbc:sqlserver://192.162.101.111;databaseName=test</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>root</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>testroot</value>
        </property>
        <property name="maxActive" value="100"/>
        <property name="maxWait" value="10000"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="10"/>
    </bean>


<!--- Spring security configuration --->
<security:http auto-config="true"  >
<!-- Restrict URLs based on role -->
<security:intercept-url pattern="/POC/" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/common/reportgenerator/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

<security:intercept-url pattern="/common/**" access="ROLE_BIDDER,ROLE_OFFICER" />

<security:intercept-url pattern="/bidder/**" access="ROLE_BIDDER" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/officer/**" access="ROLE_OFFICER" />


<!--  Override default login and logout pages -->
<security:form-login login-page="/Login"
login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
default-target-url="/"
always-use-default-target="true"
authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
<security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</security:http>


<security:authentication-manager>
       <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref=""  >
       <security:user-service >
        <security:user   name="krupa@egp.com"                           password="c06d3569e5cb23eea69c8e264cbb43d817b95c2d"                     authorities="ROLE_OFFICER" />
    </security:user-service>
    <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
    users-by-username-query="select  emailid username,lower(password)   password,'true' enabled from tbl_LoginDetails where emailid=?"
    authorities-by-username-query="select a.emailid username,b.authority from   tbl_LoginDetails a,tbl_UserRoles b where a.userId=b.userId and a.emailid=?"     />
       <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" base64="false"/>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder"></bean>
</beans>
```

---

### The WEB.xml contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
<listener>
        <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
   </listener-class>
</listener>


 <!-- Spring Security filter entry -->
 <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

---

### Controller Details:

```
package com.abc.controller;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController  
{
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("controller");
    @RequestMapping
    public String showHome(ModelMap model) {
        logger.debug("this is a sample log message.");

    if(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated() && !SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("anonymousUser"))
    {
    User user = null;
    user=(User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    System.out.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getCredentials());

    if(user !=null )
    {
    String name = user.getUsername();
    model.addAttribute("username", name);
    }

 }
return "home";
}

    @RequestMapping(value="/loginfailed", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginerror(ModelMap model) {
        logger.debug("login failed");
        model.addAttribute("error", "true");
        return "login";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/logout")
    public String logout(ModelMap model) {
        logger.debug("log out");
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/bidder/dashboard")
    public String bidderDashboard(ModelMap model) {
        return "bidder/dashboard";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/officer/dashboard")
    public String officerDashboard(ModelMap model) {
        return "officer/dashboard";
    }

}
```

---

### My Login Jsp Page is as per bellow:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
<style>
.errorblock {
    color: #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffEEEE;
    border: 3px solid #ff0000;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 16px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload='document.f.j_username.focus();'>
    <h3>Login </h3>

    <c:if test="${not empty error}">
        <div class="errorblock">
            Your login attempt was not successful, try again.<br />                 Caused :<spring:message code="SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"           text="Default Text" />
        </div>
    </c:if>

    <form name='f' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />"
        method='POST'>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='j_username' value=''>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type='password' name='j_password' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
                    value="submit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><input name="reset" type="reset" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Comment: Nice question... I have same problem.
Hope someone helps as soon as possible. :)

Answer (score 1):

Is that really the configuration file you are running with? It looks like there are a few problems with it and it

The syntax you have posted for `<authentication-manager>` is incorrect. You should have multiple `authentication-provider` elements in order to configure multiple user data sources to authenticate against. You only have one and the `jdbc-user-service` will probably be ignored in favour of the `user-service` element.

There is no `password-encoder` associated with the `user-service` element, so it won't work with encoded passwords, though you say it does. Are you sure?

Make sure that the value retrieved from the SQL query for the password exactly matches that calculated by the password encoder for the correct password (check it manually).

If none of these help, please provide a clearer explanation of what actually goes wrong. What doesn't work, and what version numbers are you using? Above all, what is the output of the debug log during a login? That is most likely to provide some pointers to what is happening.

Also, the `web.xml`, controller and login page are unlikely to be relevant for a password encoding issue (if you can log in successfully with one configuration but not another), so you can probably remove those.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are two things missing!

1. you cannot have two different elements in on . So  either delete one of those or add another authentication-provider.

2. I cannot see where the password provided by the user is encrypted. You know, both passwords (the one in database, and the other which user gives) should be encrypted and be the same.